# <printf>(or size_t or other) cannot be resolved

Tags: c++, linker-errors, eclipse-cdt

I have installed e2studio which is based on eclipse plus the necessary toolchain for my microprocessor and now I am trying to build a project that I received from the microprocessor makers. It does not build. 
The first error that comes is ".... cannot be resolved" (and this includes `printf`, `size_t` and all int types such as `uint32_t`)

Now, I have looked in the internet for solutions all day. Some are in stack overflow and mentioned `#include <stdio.h>` or something like that. It does not work for Renesas mbed-style projects

Other suggestion (for eclipse based IDEs) was to re-build the indexes, I tried that but the errors are still there.

Can anyone suggest me something to try?

(note the other error I got is "recipe for target `cmsis_nvic.o` failed")

EDIT: 
I am including an exact copy of the console message as requested. Note however that the error I am asking about seems to *not* appear in the console. It appears in the "Problems" window next to console

```
09:17:15 **** プロジェクト FirstSimple に対する構成 Debug の 逐次ビルド ****
Configuration for Project FirstSimple Sequential build of Debug
make all 
'ビルドするファイル(File to Build): ../mbed-os/targets/TARGET_RENESAS/TARGET_RZA1XX/common/cmsis_nvic.c'
'呼び出し中(Calling): Cross ARM C Compiler'
arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-a9 -march=armv7-a -marm -mthumb-interwork -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfpv3 -mno-unaligned-access -O2 -fmessage-length=0 -fsigned-char -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-common -Wall -Wextra  -g -DDEVICE_ERROR_PATTERN=1 -DARM_MATH_CA9 -D__FPU_PRESENT -D__MBED__=1 -DDEVICE_I2CSLAVE=1 -DTARGET_LIKE_MBED -DDEVICE_PORTINOUT=1 -DDEVICE_PORTIN=1 -DTOOLCHAIN_object -DDEVICE_SERIAL_ASYNCH=1 -DDEVICE_RTC -D__CMSIS_RTOS -D__EVAL -DTOOLCHAIN_GCC -DTARGET_CORTEX_A -DDEVICE_CAN=1 -DMBED_BUILD_TIMESTAMP=1487815611.57 -DDEVICE_I2C_ASYNCH=1 -DTARGET_UVISOR_UNSUPPORTED -D__MBED_CMSIS_RTOS_CA9 -DTARGET_LIKE_CORTEX_A9 -DDEVICE_SERIAL=1 -DTARGET_MBRZA1LU -DDEVICE_INTERRUPTIN=1 -DDEVICE_I2C=1 -DDEVICE_PORTOUT=1 -DDEVICE_STDIO_MESSAGES=1 -DDEVICE_SPI_ASYNCH=1 -DTARGET_RENESAS -DTARGET_RELEASE -DDEVICE_SERIAL_FC=1 -DTARGET_RZA1XX -DTARGET_RZA1UL -DTARGET_A9 -D__CORTEX_A9 -DTARGET_GR_LYCHEE -DTARGET_FF_ARDUINO -DTOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM -DDEVICE_SPI=1 -DDEVICE_SPISLAVE=1 -DDEVICE_ANALOGIN=1 -DDEVICE_PWMOUT=1 -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-os" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-os\cmsis" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-os\cmsis\TOOLCHAIN_GCC" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-os\cmsis\TOOLCHAIN_GCC\TARGET_CORTEX_A" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-os\drivers" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-os\events" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-os\events\equeue" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-os\features" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-os\features\netsocket" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-os\features\filesystem" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-os\features\filesystem\bd" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-os\features\filesystem\fat" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-os\features\filesystem\fat\ChaN" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-os\hal" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-os\hal\storage_abstraction" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-os\platform" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-os\rtos" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-os\rtos\rtx" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-os\rtos\rtx\TARGET_CORTEX_A" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-os\rtos\rtx\TARGET_CORTEX_A\TOOLCHAIN_GCC" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-os\targets" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-os\targets\TARGET_RENESAS" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-os\targets\TARGET_RENESAS\TARGET_RZA1XX" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-os\targets\TARGET_RENESAS\TARGET_RZA1XX\common" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-os\targets\TARGET_RENESAS\TARGET_RZA1XX\TARGET_GR_LYCHEE" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-os\targets\TARGET_RENESAS\TARGET_RZA1XX\TARGET_GR_LYCHEE\device" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-os\targets\TARGET_RENESAS\TARGET_RZA1XX\TARGET_GR_LYCHEE\device\inc" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-os\targets\TARGET_RENESAS\TARGET_RZA1XX\TARGET_GR_LYCHEE\device\inc\iobitmasks" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-os\targets\TARGET_RENESAS\TARGET_RZA1XX\TARGET_GR_LYCHEE\device\inc\iodefines" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-os\targets\TARGET_RENESAS\TARGET_RZA1XX\TARGET_GR_LYCHEE\device\TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-os\targets\TARGET_RENESAS\TARGET_RZA1XX\TARGET_GR_LYCHEE\TARGET_MBED_MBRZA1LU" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\components" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\components\LCD_config_lychee" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\components\MAX9867_RBSP" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\components\TLV320_RBSP" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\dcache-control" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\EasyAttach_CameraAndLCD" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\GR-PEACH_video" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\GR-PEACH_video\targets" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\GR-PEACH_video\targets\TARGET_RZA1UL" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\GR-PEACH_video\targets\TARGET_RZA1UL\drivers" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\GR-PEACH_video\targets\TARGET_RZA1UL\drivers\vdc5" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\GR-PEACH_video\targets\TARGET_RZA1UL\drivers\vdc5\include" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\GraphicsFramework" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\GraphicsFramework\config" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\GraphicsFramework\jcu" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\GraphicsFramework\jcu\inc" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\GraphicsFramework\ospl" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\GraphicsFramework\ospl\inc" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\GraphicsFramework\ospl\src" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\R_BSP" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\R_BSP\api" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\R_BSP\RenesasBSP" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\R_BSP\RenesasBSP\drv_inc" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\R_BSP\RenesasBSP\drv_src" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\R_BSP\RenesasBSP\drv_src\dma" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\R_BSP\RenesasBSP\drv_src\scux" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\R_BSP\RenesasBSP\drv_src\ssif" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\R_BSP\tools" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\SDBlockDevice_GRBoard" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\SDBlockDevice_GRBoard\sd-driver-hs" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\SDBlockDevice_GRBoard\sd-driver-hs\features" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\SDBlockDevice_GRBoard\sd-driver-hs\features\filesystem" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\SDBlockDevice_GRBoard\sd-driver-hs\features\filesystem\sd" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\SDBlockDevice_GRBoard\sd-driver-hs\features\filesystem\spif" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\SDBlockDevice_GRBoard\sd-driver-hs\features\filesystem\test" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\USBDevice" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\USBDevice\USBAudio" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\USBDevice\USBDevice" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\USBDevice\USBDevice\TARGET_RENESAS" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\USBDevice\USBDevice\TARGET_RENESAS\TARGET_RZA1XX" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\USBDevice\USBDevice\TARGET_RENESAS\TARGET_RZA1XX\inc" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\USBDevice\USBDevice\TARGET_RENESAS\TARGET_RZA1XX\usb0\inc" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\USBDevice\USBDevice\TARGET_RENESAS\TARGET_RZA1XX\usb1\inc" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\USBDevice\USBHID" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\USBDevice\USBMIDI" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\USBDevice\USBMSD" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\USBDevice\USBSerial" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\USBHost_custom\USBHost" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\USBHost_custom\USBHost\TARGET_RENESAS" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\USBHost_custom\USBHost\TARGET_RENESAS\TARGET_RZA1XX" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\USBHost_custom\USBHost\TARGET_RENESAS\TARGET_RZA1XX\inc" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\USBHost_custom\USBHost\TARGET_RENESAS\TARGET_RZA1XX\usb0" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\USBHost_custom\USBHost\TARGET_RENESAS\TARGET_RZA1XX\usb0\inc" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\USBHost_custom\USBHost\TARGET_RENESAS\TARGET_RZA1XX\usb1" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\USBHost_custom\USBHost\TARGET_RENESAS\TARGET_RZA1XX\usb1\inc" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\USBHost_custom\USBHost3GModule" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\USBHost_custom\USBHostHID" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\USBHost_custom\USBHostHub" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\USBHost_custom\USBHostMIDI" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\USBHost_custom\USBHostMSD" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\USBHost_custom\USBHostSerial" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple" -I"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs" -include"C:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed_config.h" -std=c99 -MMD -MP -MF"mbed-os/targets/TARGET_RENESAS/TARGET_RZA1XX/common/cmsis_nvic.d" -MT"mbed-os/targets/TARGET_RENESAS/TARGET_RZA1XX/common/cmsis_nvic.o" -c -o "mbed-os/targets/TARGET_RENESAS/TARGET_RZA1XX/common/cmsis_nvic.o" "../mbed-os/targets/TARGET_RENESAS/TARGET_RZA1XX/common/cmsis_nvic.c"
mbed-os/targets/TARGET_RENESAS/TARGET_RZA1XX/common/subdir.mk:30: recipe for target 'mbed-os/targets/TARGET_RENESAS/TARGET_RZA1XX/common/cmsis_nvic.o' failed
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-a9 -march=armv7-a -marm -mthumb-interwork -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfpv3 -mno-unaligned-access -O2 -fmessage-length=0 -fsigned-char -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-common -Wall -Wextra -g -DDEVICE_ERROR_PATTERN=1 -DARM_MATH_CA9 -D__FPU_PRESENT -D__MBED__=1 -DDEVICE_I2CSLAVE=1 -DTARGET_LIKE_MBED -DDEVICE_PORTINOUT=1 -DDEVICE_PORTIN=1 -DTOOLCHAIN_object -DDEVICE_SERIAL_ASYNCH=1 -DDEVICE_RTC -D__CMSIS_RTOS -D__EVAL -DTOOLCHAIN_GCC -DTARGET_CORTEX_A -DDEVICE_CAN=1 -DMBED_BUILD_TIMESTAMP=1487815611.57 -DDEVICE_I2C_ASYNCH=1 -DTARGET_UVISOR_UNSUPPORTED -D__MBED_CMSIS_RTOS_CA9 -DTARGET_LIKE_CORTEX_A9 -DDEVICE_SERIAL=1 -DTARGET_MBRZA1LU -DDEVICE_INTERRUPTIN=1 -DDEVICE_I2C=1 -DDEVICE_PORTOUT=1 -DDEVICE_STDIO_MESSAGES=1 -DDEVICE_SPI_ASYNCH=1 -DTARGET_RENESAS -DTARGET_RELEASE -DDEVICE_SERIAL_FC=1 -DTARGET_RZA1XX -DTARGET_RZA1UL -DTARGET_A9 -D__CORTEX_A9 -DTARGET_GR_LYCHEE -DTARGET_FF_ARDUINO -DTOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM -DDEVICE_SPI=1 -DDEVICE_SPISLAVE=1 -DDEVICE_ANALOGIN=1 -DDEVICE_PWMOUT=1 -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-os -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-os\cmsis -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-os\cmsis\TOOLCHAIN_GCC -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-os\cmsis\TOOLCHAIN_GCC\TARGET_CORTEX_A -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-os\drivers -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-os\events -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-os\events\equeue -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-os\features -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-os\features\netsocket -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-os\features\filesystem -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-os\features\filesystem\bd -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-os\features\filesystem\fat -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-os\features\filesystem\fat\ChaN -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-os\hal -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-os\hal\storage_abstraction -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-os\platform -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-os\rtos -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-os\rtos\rtx -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-os\rtos\rtx\TARGET_CORTEX_A -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-os\rtos\rtx\TARGET_CORTEX_A\TOOLCHAIN_GCC -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-os\targets -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-os\targets\TARGET_RENESAS -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-os\targets\TARGET_RENESAS\TARGET_RZA1XX -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-os\targets\TARGET_RENESAS\TARGET_RZA1XX\common -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-os\targets\TARGET_RENESAS\TARGET_RZA1XX\TARGET_GR_LYCHEE -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-os\targets\TARGET_RENESAS\TARGET_RZA1XX\TARGET_GR_LYCHEE\device -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-os\targets\TARGET_RENESAS\TARGET_RZA1XX\TARGET_GR_LYCHEE\device\inc -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-os\targets\TARGET_RENESAS\TARGET_RZA1XX\TARGET_GR_LYCHEE\device\inc\iobitmasks -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-os\targets\TARGET_RENESAS\TARGET_RZA1XX\TARGET_GR_LYCHEE\device\inc\iodefines -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-os\targets\TARGET_RENESAS\TARGET_RZA1XX\TARGET_GR_LYCHEE\device\TOOLCHAIN_GCC_ARM -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-os\targets\TARGET_RENESAS\TARGET_RZA1XX\TARGET_GR_LYCHEE\TARGET_MBED_MBRZA1LU -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\components -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\components\LCD_config_lychee -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\components\MAX9867_RBSP -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\components\TLV320_RBSP -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\dcache-control -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\EasyAttach_CameraAndLCD -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\GR-PEACH_video -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\GR-PEACH_video\targets -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\GR-PEACH_video\targets\TARGET_RZA1UL -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\GR-PEACH_video\targets\TARGET_RZA1UL\drivers -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\GR-PEACH_video\targets\TARGET_RZA1UL\drivers\vdc5 -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\GR-PEACH_video\targets\TARGET_RZA1UL\drivers\vdc5\include -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\GraphicsFramework -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\GraphicsFramework\config -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\GraphicsFramework\jcu -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\GraphicsFramework\jcu\inc -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\GraphicsFramework\ospl -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\GraphicsFramework\ospl\inc -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\GraphicsFramework\ospl\src -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\R_BSP -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\R_BSP\api -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\R_BSP\RenesasBSP -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\R_BSP\RenesasBSP\drv_inc -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\R_BSP\RenesasBSP\drv_src -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\R_BSP\RenesasBSP\drv_src\dma -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\R_BSP\RenesasBSP\drv_src\scux -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\R_BSP\RenesasBSP\drv_src\ssif -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\R_BSP\tools -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\SDBlockDevice_GRBoard -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\SDBlockDevice_GRBoard\sd-driver-hs -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\SDBlockDevice_GRBoard\sd-driver-hs\features -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\SDBlockDevice_GRBoard\sd-driver-hs\features\filesystem -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\SDBlockDevice_GRBoard\sd-driver-hs\features\filesystem\sd -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\SDBlockDevice_GRBoard\sd-driver-hs\features\filesystem\spif -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\SDBlockDevice_GRBoard\sd-driver-hs\features\filesystem\test -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\USBDevice -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\USBDevice\USBAudio -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\USBDevice\USBDevice -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\USBDevice\USBDevice\TARGET_RENESAS -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\USBDevice\USBDevice\TARGET_RENESAS\TARGET_RZA1XX -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\USBDevice\USBDevice\TARGET_RENESAS\TARGET_RZA1XX\inc -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\USBDevice\USBDevice\TARGET_RENESAS\TARGET_RZA1XX\usb0\inc -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\USBDevice\USBDevice\TARGET_RENESAS\TARGET_RZA1XX\usb1\inc -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\USBDevice\USBHID -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\USBDevice\USBMIDI -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\USBDevice\USBMSD -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\USBDevice\USBSerial -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\USBHost_custom\USBHost -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\USBHost_custom\USBHost\TARGET_RENESAS -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\USBHost_custom\USBHost\TARGET_RENESAS\TARGET_RZA1XX -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\USBHost_custom\USBHost\TARGET_RENESAS\TARGET_RZA1XX\inc -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\USBHost_custom\USBHost\TARGET_RENESAS\TARGET_RZA1XX\usb0 -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\USBHost_custom\USBHost\TARGET_RENESAS\TARGET_RZA1XX\usb0\inc -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\USBHost_custom\USBHost\TARGET_RENESAS\TARGET_RZA1XX\usb1 -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\USBHost_custom\USBHost\TARGET_RENESAS\TARGET_RZA1XX\usb1\inc -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\USBHost_custom\USBHost3GModule -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\USBHost_custom\USBHostHID -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\USBHost_custom\USBHostHub -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\USBHost_custom\USBHostMIDI -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\USBHost_custom\USBHostMSD -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs\USBHost_custom\USBHostSerial -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple -IC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed-gr-libs -includeC:\Users\Admin\e2_studio\workspace\FirstSimple\mbed_config.h -std=c99 -MMD -MP -MFmbed-os/targets/TARGET_RENESAS/TARGET_RZA1XX/common/cmsis_nvic.d -MTmbed-os/targets/TARGET_RENESAS/TARGET_RZA1XX/common/cmsis_nvic.o -c -o mbed-os/targets/TARGET_RENESAS/TARGET_RZA1XX/common/cmsis_nvic.o ../mbed-os/targets/TARGET_RENESAS/TARGET_RZA1XX/common/cmsis_nvic.c, ...) failed.
make (e=2): �w�肳�ꂽ�t�@�C����������܂���B

make: *** [mbed-os/targets/TARGET_RENESAS/TARGET_RZA1XX/common/cmsis_nvic.o] Error 2

09:17:16 Build Failed. 2 errors, 0 warnings. (took 1s.301ms)
```

Comment: If you open the "Console" view you should get all the build errors. Please include them. As your problem sounds like errors when you build (run the compiler) the solutions about the indexer are not relevant. Also, Renesas also has its own support forum http://renesasrulz.com/

Comment: Don't make us guess. If you have an error message, provide an **exact** copy of it in your question. As currently written, this question cannot be answered.

Comment: The messages you posted are saying that the build system could not launch the compiler; this is unrelated to whatever you are talking about at the start of your post